# I want to finish this sorting technique

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

How would I start to code this sorting technique ( I changed it from algorithm because it is not efficient to really make a code that can do this. It is only for knowledge purposes) to do this specific task?

so lets say we have a jumbled array with 1,0,-44, 5,3,1.
It is suppose to sort in a way that the new array will put the lowest in the lower area and the highest in the highest area so.

[-,-,-,-,-,-](empty array. dashes signify empty spot in the array)

[-44, -, -, -, -, 5]

then it suppose to do

[-44,0,-,-,3,5]

then

[-44,0,1,1,3,5]

and the sorting is done.

The same thing has to happen but with odd numbers as well.

Edit: Yes by odd numbers I do mean odd numbered array.

Also does what significance does this type of technique have?

EDIT: Here is the video of the program... yes you will see that it is highly inefficient. It is because I just made it before I knew about sorting algorithms and O(n) stuff... Also you will notice there are two arrays.... very inefficient as well...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4NIDKS-zbM&feature=youtu.be

Comment: _"The same thing has to happen but with odd numbers as well."_ What do you mean? Do you mean, "this algorithm must also work for an array with an odd number of elements"?

Comment: _"what significance does this type of technique have?"_ What is "significance"?

Comment: It looks like this is a bidirectional [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). The normal selection sort always chooses the lowest (or highest), while your algorithm chooses both the lowest *and* highest in each step. A good way to get started would be to modify the code from the Wikipedia entry for selection sort.

Comment: Also known as cocktail sort :)

Comment: The technique is O(n^{2}) time + O(2n) space and that there are *significantly* more efficient algorithms in regard to time for interesting values of *n*, and slightly more efficient algorithms in regard to space. With O(2n) space, even two heaps would work.

Comment: Edit: Yes by odd numbers I do mean odd numbered array.

Answer (score 1):

- Start with automating a test for result correctness.
- Figure out what order of growth to expect for run time (or number of comparisons & moves/swaps) for increasing input (and output) size.
- Make your description of what should be the result a method/procedure/word comment, the notion of how to proceed a code comment.
- Code the sort.
- Test it using sorted, reverse sorted and random input, at least.
- Decide on details like handling of duplicate values (including stability), whether in place sort should be possibleTry etc. (Revise test on spec changes, re-test in case of code changes.)
- Try to describe this method in terms of "traditional" sorting algorithms (much like selection sort, but, hm, symmetrical or double ended or bidirectional or ...). Plug the key words of this into your favourite search engine and see what and how others have done.
- Benchmark against "traditional" sorting implementations.
- Form your opinion about the significance of the approach.